# How to create a loaded `nofile` buffer without loading a file?

Tags: buffers

This script creates a 'nofile' buffer and loads it so it can be edited:

```
let n = bufadd('foo')
setbufvar(n, '&bt', 'nofile')
bufload(n)
```

But it has a big problem: The call to `bufload` will read a file named `foo` if it exists. This is a `nofile` buffer that should not touch any files on disk.

Then I tried to tackle this issue in a different way: Create a no-name buffer then set its name. But the only set-name function/command I can find is `:file [name]` which only works on the current buffer. This is a command not a function, so I get no return values. And it involves too much complexity such as `BufEnter` and `WinEnter` autocommands.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to ask `bufload` not to load the file on disk?
2. Can we rename a buffer using a function `bufrename({buf})`, with the buffer number as an argument?

Comment: what happens when you don't give the buf a name e.g., `bufadd('')`?

Comment: @Mass That buffer is loaded with nothing (after `bufload`), but without a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set custom BufReadCmd

```
let bnr = bufadd("foo")
call setbufvar(bnr, "&buftype", "nofile")
call printf("au BufReadCmd <buffer=%d> :", bnr)->execute()
call bufload(bnr)
```

Comment: This should work. I was merely looking for a function and didn't think about autocommands. I still prefer functions though, but there seems to be none?

Comment: @Cyker No, and you don't need it for this case.